# NLTK POS tag: how to put the 'Word' and its corresponding 'POS Tag' in a DataFrame

Tags: python, list, dataframe, syntax, nltk

I have a list like 
        `list = ['about','above','account','address','after']`
 which i passed into the **nltk pos tag** function and the output looks like this in form of a list:

```
[('about', 'IN'),('above', 'JJ'),('account', 'NN'),('address', 'NN'),('after', 'IN')]
```

now i need to display these words and pos tags seperately in form of a **DataFrame** so the output looks something like this:

```
Words   Pos Tags
about     IN
above     JJ
account   NN
address   NN
after     IN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should be easy:

```
In [15]: data = [('about', 'IN'),('above', 'JJ'),('account', 'NN'),('address', 'NN'),('after', 'IN')]

In [16]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Word', 'POS'])

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
      Word POS
0    about  IN
1    above  JJ
2  account  NN
3  address  NN
4    after  IN
```